# Javascript: Show element in a form when something is valid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation

How can I display an element when something in a form is validated?

Here's some of my code:

signup.php

```
<div  class="wrapper">
   <div class="error-div" id="zipcode-error" ></div>
   <label>Zip code:</label>
   <input type="text" class="input" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" />
</div>

 <!-- this div is hidden, it can only be seen when zip code is validated -->
 <div  class="wrapper" id="city-wrapper" >
    <div class="error-div" id="city-error" ></div>
        <label>City:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="city" id="city" >
 </div>
 <!-- this div is hidden, it can only be seen when zip code is validated -->
```

signup_validation.js

```
$('#zipcode').keyup(function() {
    $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=zipcode', { zipcode: $(this).val() }, 
     function(result){
     $('#zipcode-error').html(result).show("slow");
    });

});
```

validate_signup.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['zipcode'])){
    $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
    if(empty($zip)){
       echo "*Zipcode required!";
    }elseif( (strlen($zip)<5) OR (strlen($zip)>5)){
       echo "*Must be 5 digit!";
    }elseif(!is_numeric($zip)){
       echo "Must be numeric!";
    }else{
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE zip = '{$zip}'");
       $found_zip = mysql_num_rows($query);
       if($found_zip =1){
         echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' /><input type = 'hidden' name='show-city' id='show-city' />";
       } else{
         echo "Zip not found";
       }

    }

 }
```

When zipcode is validated i want to display the City div, but i don't know how.

The situation goes like this: a user must input his/her valid zipcode, once it's validated, the hidden div will come up and display it's corresponding City on the text field provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($found_zip =1){
         echo "found||<img src='images/check.jpg' /><input type = 'hidden' name='show-city' id='show-city' />";
       } else{
         echo "error||error";
       }
//then ur js
$('#zipcode').blur(function() {
    var zip = $(this).val();
    $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=zipcode', { zipcode: zip }, 
     function(result){
     var respArr = result.split("||");
      if("error" ==respArr[0]) {
        $('#zipcode-error').html(result).show("slow");
      }
      else {
        //show your hidden div here
        $("#urHidden").show("slow");
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: I will surely put any comment after my testing sir, thanks:-)

Comment: I notice that whenever i type on the zip input, City div comes up.

Comment: you can change the event keyup to something like blur, see the edited code

Answer (score 1):

When the return of the post is empty you will show the div

```
echo "<div id='city_holder'>No City</div>";
if(isset($_POST['zipcode'])){
    $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
    if(empty($zip)){
       echo "*Zipcode required!";
    }elseif( (strlen($zip)<5) OR (strlen($zip)>5)){
       echo "*Must be 5 digit!";
    }elseif(!is_numeric($zip)){
       echo "Must be numeric!";
    }else{
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE zip = '{$zip}'");
       $found_zip = mysql_num_rows($query);
       if($found_zip =1){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
echo "<div id='city_holder'>".$row['city_name']."</div>";

         echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' /><input type = 'hidden' name='show-city' id='show-city' />";
       } else{
         echo "Zip not found";
       }

    }

 } 

$('#zipcode').keyup(function() {
    $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=zipcode', { zipcode: $(this).val() }, 
     function(result){

     if($('#city_holder').html() != 'No City')
{
$('#city').val($('#city_holder').html()); //to fill up the input
$('#city-wrapper').show("slow");//to show the div 
}
else{
$('#city').val(" "); //to empty the input 
$('#city-wrapper').hide("slow");//to hide the div
     $('#zipcode-error').html(result).show("slow");
}

    });

});
```

Hope it helps you

Don't forget to set the city_holder to hidden with your CSS

If you want any other help comment it

Comment: Thanks sir, ..I will surely test your suggestion.

Comment: Good Luck :) tell me the result

Comment: The situation goes like this: a user must input his/her valid zipcode, once it's validated, the hidden div will come up and display it's corresponding City on the text field provided.

Comment: then you also should fill the city name somewhere after you fetched it from the DB am i right ?

Comment: A textfield named "city" will have the value of corresponding City base on User's zipcode.

Comment: City appears even if it's not validated..meaning , anything you type on the zip input, city div appears..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5576/discussion-between-userb-and-milagro)